# gojs-react. When onModelChange happens, how can I differ model changes made by me programmatically from changed made via UI?

Tags: gojs

When I edit the diagram via UI, onModelChange event happens.
When I edit model of diagram via code (model.set(node, deletable, false)), onModelChange event occurs.

I want to have a way to ignore second type of changes. Because I do them during handling the first type of changes. So I am getting recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Your **onModelChange** handler should be setting **skipsDiagramUpdate** to true. This prevents the handler from being called on changes the GoJS model already knows of.

https://gojs.net/latest/intro/react.html#UsingWrapperComponentWithinApp
https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/gojs-react-basic